# Unable to create a different homepage view for a different user with MVC

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, restful-authentication

I am relatively new to the Model-View-Controller Paradigm and the MEAN Stack. I just finished following this tutorial : http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/mean-stack-tutorial-part-4-angularjs/

I was wondering based on the code above, is it possible to have different views for different users upon login. For example, if I am a manufacturer I can create products, but if I am a distributor I can only view products. After research I have found I can do ng-show in the Angular view, but that doesn't work for me, as I want it to be different for different users. I also found out, I can change the users services code, but I am unsure in what way.  Can anyone help,or does anyone know of any tutorials ?

Comment: look into using user roles

Answer (score 0):

yes this can be achieved by simply following the below link : 
`https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission`

Comment: Would it be possible to set roles like ['manufacturer' , 'distributor'] instead of the classic ['admin', 'user ]

Comment: Yes it is possible. Open the link and scroll to the title - "Defining roles" over there as you can see he has defined three roles 
  // anonymous: When there is not user currenly logged in
  // normal: A user with isAdmin = false
  // admin: A user with isAdmin = true
following that depending on your requirement you need to declare manufacturer and distributer.